# How can I avoid this infinite do-while loop?

Tags: java, loops

I need the user to input an integer x such as 0<=x<=4, and need the user to retry until it finally inserts a valid integer.

This is my code:

```
do {
    System.out.println("Input an integer number between 0 and 4 (inclusive): ");
    if (in.hasNextInt()) {
        n = in.nextInt();
    }

    if (n >= 0 && n <= 4) {
        valid = true;
    }
} while (!valid);
```

I tried inserting "s" but as soon as I press enter the cycle loops and continues to print the string printed by that `System.out.println`. How can I fix that?

Comment: what do you think `hasNextInt()` returns when you input that `"s"`?

Comment: Hint: if `hasNextInt()` returns false, you should consume the "not an integer" token. So you want something in an `else` clause...

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the `has` methods unless you know what you are doing; the `nextInt` method will block until the user enters something. If they entered a non-integer, then you get an exception; this is usually what you want. If you want to gracefully handle (as in, print to the user they typed in a wrong thing) non-integral input, you can catch that exception and treat it as an erroneous flow that you then improve, or, you update the idea behind this code to state that, if you can handle non-integer input just as well, that you aren't actually asking for an integer at all; in that case, call `.next()` instead, and parse it into an integer if it is one via `Integer.parseInt`, or if not, state that the user entered a non-valid value and move on. In no case do you need a `has` method, really.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you want is to read *any* input (by using `next()` on the Scanner), then try to convert it to an `int`, and finally break from the loop if the value is in the specified range.

Using [`hasNextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt()) will return true/false which appears to be what you want, but it also importantly *"does not advance past any input."* So if you enter "s", `hasNextInt()` will return false, the "s" input will remain unconsumed, and each time through the loop it will again call `hasNextInt()` (which will again return false), etc.

Here's an edit to your code showing how to do this correctly:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
do {
    System.out.print("Input an integer number between 0 and 4 (inclusive): ");

    try {
        String next = in.next();
        int n = Integer.parseInt(next);
        if (n >= 0 && n <= 4) {
            System.out.println("valid input: " + n);
            break;
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // print a warning message if you want, "only integer values allowed"
    }

} while (true);
```

Another way to make this work would be to continue using `hasNextInt()`, but then also: if the result is false, add code that will consume whatever non-`int` token is there.